# log 'memory exhausted" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a webservice that will run daily at a certain time using CronTab, I'm testing and trying to log all kind of problem but i can't find a way to log the "memory exhausted" , since laravel doesn't log it in Storage/logs/ .

i need a way to log "memory exhausted" error .
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] to add some meaningful code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: im sorry if my message is not understandable but i will try to do so

Comment: Did you checked `error_log` file?

Comment: i don't know where it is , normally i would look into /storage/logs , where is it located ?